# Parallel training of ensembled neural networks using torch.multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch

I'm trying to implement an ensemble model using `pytorch`, and as there're some independent models, I want to traing the models in parallel using `torch.multiprocessing`, However, I always get `Too many open files` error.

Here is a minimal example that reproduce the error:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from   torch.multiprocessing import Pool

class MyModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nn = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(10, 10),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU(), 
                nn.Linear(10, 10), 
                nn.ReLU()
                )

    def train(self):
        pass

class EnsembleModel:
    def __init__(self, K):
        self.K      = K;
        self.models = [MyModel() for i in range(self.K)]

    def f(self, i):
        return i

    def train(self):

        pool = Pool(processes = 3)
        ret  = pool.map(self.f, range(self.K))
        print(ret)


md = EnsembleModel(15);
md.train()
```

And this is the error message:

````
/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py:153: RuntimeWarning: received malformed or improperly-truncated ancillary data
  msg, ancdata, flags, addr = sock.recvmsg(1, socket.CMSG_LEN(bytes_size))
Process ForkPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 151, in rebuild_storage_fd
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 58, in detach
    return reduction.recv_handle(conn)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 182, in recv_handle
    return recvfds(s, 1)[0]
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 172, in recvfds
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid data received')
RuntimeError: Invalid data received
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 149, in _serve
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 50, in send
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 176, in send_handle
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 460, in fromfd
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 142, in _serve
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 453, in accept
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 593, in accept
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 205, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 142, in _serve
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 453, in accept
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 593, in accept
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 205, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 405, in _handle_workers
    pool._maintain_pool()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 246, in _maintain_pool
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/alaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 65, in _launch
    parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

```
````

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this problem?